# .net mvc issue for bootstrap in release mode

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

[image]

the above controls are rending correctly when I debug in .net vs 2015 in mvc application, but when I publish in release mode I am getting this below:

[image]

I added `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` and `deubg= false` in release mode and the bootstrap controls are not working in release mode.

and `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
and media queries

`@media only screen and (max-width: 700px)`

I want width of controls as in debug mode.

Comment: There's probably an issue minifying your css and / or your javascript. Reference them directly from a CDN to check if the issue's there.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. yes I checked only keeping CDN site and published, but the still same issue, it's showing more width